# What is the derivative with respect to a matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ and $\Gamma \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\Gamma(\mathbf{x}) = (\gamma(x_1), \dots, \gamma(x_d))$, what is the derivative of $\Gamma(A \mathbf{x})$ with respect to $A$?

I thought that by chain rule we have
$$
\frac{d\Gamma(A\mathbf{x})}{dA} = \sum_{i,j=1}^d \frac{d\Gamma((A\mathbf{x})_i)}
{d (A\mathbf{x})_i} \frac{d (Ax)_i}{d A_{ij}} e_i \otimes e_j
$$
but shouldn't that be a tensor of order $3$ instead?

EDIT:

Ok, so thanks to the comments, I guess that this should be the correct answer?
$$
\frac{d\Gamma(A\mathbf{x})}{dA} = \sum_{i,j=1}^d \left(\sum_{k=1} \left(\frac{d\Gamma((A\mathbf{x})_i)}
{d (A\mathbf{x})_i}\right)_k e_k \right) \otimes\left( \frac{d (Ax)_i}{d A_{ij}} e_i \otimes e_j\right)
$$

Comment: in fact it is a 3-tensor. Notice that the first term in your sum is a vector

Comment: Nice thanks for checking!

Comment: Yes, I think it's a 3 tensor, the reason from my old comment was off. The chain rule forces you to contract. There are two free indices of $\Gamma$ with a initially free index of the differentiated component of $Ax$, and then by the chain rule you match that index with "a component index of $Ax$" (not the two derivative indices of $A$ of $dAx/dA$. This gives 3-1+1=3

Comment: Darn it, sorry. The logic was right but of course $\Gamma$ has one not two free indices for the component, and then one when it's differentiated. This gives $2 - 1 + 2 = 3$. Or alternatively, the total derivative of $\Gamma$ is a two tensor and this acts on the three tensor $dAx/dA$ (5 indices), but contraction drops us down 2 (one from each).